# Do monkey bars make you taller?

Tags: physiology

My mom -- a doctor -- and my relatives seem to think that hanging off monkey bars make you taller as it "stretches" your spine.

I seriously doubt if this is true, unless you hang off monkey bars 24/7. (Literally.)

Is there any proof?

Comment: I think you answered your own question. It depends on how long you hang there.

Comment: The only thing that's happened to me while hanging off of some monkey bars is a pinched nerve in my back.

Comment: I would hope answers also address how long any effect lasts. I understand that we are slightly taller after lying down all night, but the effect wears off quickly after standing all day.

Comment: If you do it as child/teenager (i.e. not full grown person) regularly it might indeed make your grow taller. As grown-up it should only increase the stretchability of your spine, like some yoga postures do. I used to do the sun salutation every morning (~2min exercise) and could bend a lot further after only several weeks.

Comment: It didn't work for Bobby Brady...

Comment: @Oddthinking I've also heard that astronauts get taller while in space. http://uk.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20100808142202AACI7YG

Answer (score 8):

Yes. Doesn't need to be monkey bars in particular, even lying in bed will do this. The [intervertebral disks](http://indianapublicmedia.org/amomentofscience/how-tall-are-you/) in your spine are compressible, and will sag under gravity.

Of course, this is a reversible effect.

Comment: It would be nice if that article contained any references for its claims...

Comment: [Do I need to say "Welcome to Skeptics"?](http://meta.skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/1505)! Please [provide some references](http://meta.skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/5) to support your claims.

Comment: Astronauts grow up to 3% taller in space, obviously depending on how long they are there.  Essentially, this is a similar effect. http://www.space.com/19116-astronauts-taller-space-spines.html